# Google Cloud: HTTP Connection refused after VM restart

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, port, google-compute-engine

We have a node server hosted on Google Cloud.
It is handled by a VM instance on GCE and has open ports for HTTP/HTTPS.
It worked fine until I rebooted the VM instance...

If I try to connect to my API it now returns `ERR: CONNECTION REFUSED`
I'm pretty sure this is not happening because of the node server as logs are clearly showing the node server is not being accessed at all when connecting to it's IP or URL.

I can still SSH to the VM...

***BTW: iptables empty and firewall rules double checked***

Does someone know what could be the problem ?

I'd love some help... Thanks ! :D

Comment: Check that your app is lunched inside VM, then check is it listening on correct interface and port

Comment: It's properly running using `pm2`. will check about the port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm going to answer my own question so it can help anyone facing the same issue...

For me it was my Apache server not being automatically restarted... As simple as that yeah ahah!

If you're not using Apache check any routes or so in `iptables`.
My node server was listening on `8080` port but HTTP and HTTPS requests are respectively `80` and `443`...